# Why do we never hear from Elsa Granhiert again in Re:Zero?

Tags: re-zero

In the beginning of Re:Zero Elsa played as a major character and roadblock for Subaru. We also learn that she manages to escape alive and says that its not the end of her. Elsa is one of the people who seems to be against the Royal Election. The anime is already 19 episodes in and we never hear from her again. I find it strange since both Felt and Old Man Rom plays a role in the Royal Election but Elsa doesn't comeback.

Comment: I'm not really sure, if she is against Royal Election. She had a employer, and her target was Emilias insignia. It is possible, that one of dragon priestess candidates is her actual employer, trying to sabotage Emilias chance to become elected.

Comment: https://translationchicken.com/ - you can see her again in Arc 4 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elsa will not play an active role in the current arc. but she will return as one of the major antagonist (like betelgeuse) in the next arc.

Comment: Oh wow. I hope this confirms season 2. Thanks for the answer. 
I mean who doesn't want to see more cute gothic knife girl.

Comment: @Enkrypton As i recall, there is a light novel the anime is based on/taken from, so knowing what is going to happen several arcs ahead is common, but means nothing for the anime continuing.

Comment: @Enkrypton at best you need to wait for Tappei Sensei to finish arc 4 related volume which im guessing around (10 -18) which takes at minimum 2 years. 23rd/25th September 2016 will be the released of Vol 9

Answer (score 0):

She is already deceased as it was stated in the wiki. Although the cause of her death is still unknown. [More details here.](http://rezero.wikia.com/wiki/Elsa_Granhiert)